# It moves in war

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> It moves in war
>   Abhors the floor
>   Takes many forms
>   And is a controversial norm
>
> An encounter with it
>   Will leave one tearful
>   And as an omen
>   It makes many fearful
>
> Though as journeyers swear
>   It's useful where
>   One wants to prevent
>   Spoiled fare
>
> What is it?

To clarify: I'm using "norm" in the sense of something that's seen/encountered fairly often

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the fact that the riddle as originally stated had many answers that worked. Writing riddles can be great fun! I look forward to seeing more of yours.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah they're fun to come up with, and it's cool seeing people's creativity in the answers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First thing I thought of:

> Smoke.

It moves in war,

> Smoke is blown about from flame, engines, explosions, gunfire, and is spread by the wind. If the battle moves, the smoke will move with it.

Abhors the floor,

> Smoke is carried by hot air, and therefore rises. Even in an indoor fire smoke is thinnest near the ground.

Takes many forms,

> Depending on the source, smoke clouds, smoke plumes, puffs of smoke, walls of smoke, wisps of smoke....

And is a controversial norm.

> We've all seen smoke. It's not unusual. If we do see it outside of a specific context such as a bonfire or BBQ, though, most people will get excited. This could also mean smoke from cigarettes, which is a common although decreasing habit that many people dislike.

---

I answered this before a few more specific clues were added, so I'll fill them out down here.

An encounter with it
Will leave one tearful

> Smoke irritates the eyes, causing tears.

And as an omen
It makes many fearful

> As mentioned in a previous clue, if people see smoke where they don't expect it's considered a bad sign. It usually means fire or destruction of some type.

Though as journeyers swear
It's useful where
One wants to prevent
Spoiled fare

> Meat can be smoked to greatly increase the time before it spoils. In past times, this could be used for a journey as food that wouldn't rot before you reached your goal.

Comment: That's it! I've updated the original question to add more specificity. "Controversial" was in fact referring to cigarette smoking, so you're right on all accounts

Answer (score 12):

I immediately thought of a:

> flag.

Usually, in a war,

> a flag is carried by advancing troops.

It abhors the floor because:

> you are not supposed to let a flag touch the ground.

It takes many forms:

> There are obviously many different flags.

And is a controversial norm:

> Saw a headline about a controversy over flags being flown at UC Irvine I believe, not more than a few days ago.

Comment: "norm" may refer to "standard"

Comment: Ooh that's a good one! I hadn't thought of that but it fits really well. I'll leave the question open for now to see if anyone comes up with the answer I had in mind but I really like this one too.

Comment: @d'alar'cop The OP has edited the question re "norm".

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is the intended answer, but it fits everything fairly well.

> A **gun**.

*It moves in war,*

> The arms trade flourishes during war, and guns are always changing hands. Alternatively, as troops move around they take their guns with them.

*Abhors the floor,*

> You'd better not drop a gun on the floor, or it might go off and shoot you in the foot!

*Takes many forms,*

> Cannons, pistols, revolves, rifles, shotguns, machine guns, sub-machine guns, blunderbusses, ... you want me to go on?

*And is a controversial norm.*

I don't know where the OP comes from, but in the US,

> possessing a gun is a pretty normal thing (I believe over 50% of households do?), and there's a lot of controversy over gun laws.

Comment: Another good answer! It looks like I need to learn to make my riddles more specific, would it be bad etiquette to go back and add more to this riddle that invalidates the answers given already?

Comment: @Ben No, that's fine. Another riddler (Michael Rize) had to do that for several of his riddles here. FWIW I always err on the side of putting in *loads* of different clues just to make absolutely sure the riddle isn't "too broad" ... but it shouldn't be too simple either!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Money?

It moves in war,

> Economists say that war moves money.

Abhors the floor,

> Who leaves their money on the floor, or the floor meaning no money or Broke. Don't like that.

Takes many forms,

> Coins, bills, checks, gold bars, etc.

And is a controversial norm.

> Most controversies are about or at least involve money.

Comment: Oo, nice one! That could be it.

Answer (score 2):

Might it be

> spies

it moves in war

> spies get used all the times in wars. proper intelligence can make or break an army.

it abhors the floor

> spies don't like "being on the main floor". they want to stay hidden so they aren't noticed.

it takes many form

> spying can be done towards the enemies; towards your own people; and towards other companies; and towards your family (like a mother reading her child's text messages).

and is a controversial norm

> There is currently much controversy about the government spying on their own inhabitants, but when war is around, people would prefer spying to occur to save their lives.

---

I have 2 more ideas:

> workers

and

> lobbying

but I don't have time right now to explain them because I need to get some sleep. I'll explain them tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Death

It moves in war

> Death is everywhere in war, once here, once there

Abhors the floor

> Life is no longer on the ground

Takes many forms

> Can be any form of death

And is a controversial norm

An encounter with it
Will leave one tearful

> Yes, loved or near ones death will make one tearful

And as an omen
It makes many fearful

> Death an an omen makes people stop doing something

Answer (score 1):

Three out of four not sure about "abhors the floor". What about:

> border (moves in war, takes many forms, is a controversial norm)

Comment: Begin the answer with ">!"

Comment: the only thing I can think about *your answer* abhorring the floor is that many of them are in the sea, or in the middle of rivers

Answer (score 1):

The **front line** is always moving, leaving a trail of destruction, taking many shapes, being disputed over and is not a happy place; most ominous and frightful it is, however we must hold the line, lest all be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Huh.   I came up with

> Salt.

Wasn't too sure how it would fit the first verse unless it was some weird way of thinking about

> The SALT treaty from the Reagan era

But it fit the 2nd and 3rd pretty well.

EDIT:

Ok, so yeah why did it fit the 2nd and 3rd verses.

> Well I was thinking about cholorine used in swimming pools, which is a form of salt that burns the eyes (trust me on this).   But sure, tears are salty, and so "artificial tears" have salt content, so if you put it in your eyes, it will "leave one tearful", and there is a superstition about spilling salt at the table, and people throwing salt over their shoulders to ward off bad luck.  As for the 3rd verse, before refrigeration, salting was used as means of preserving meat.  It was really the 3rd verse that made me think of salt, and then looking back, it could fit the second verse as well, but the first verse is just a stretch, no doubt.   :)

Comment: You might want to clarify how it fits the 2nd and 3rd stanzas. I see connections to the salt content in tears, a pillar of salt, and meat preservation.

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fits

> Unmanned Aerial Vehicles (UAVs) or drones

It moves in war

> Obviously they move in war zones

Abhors the floor

> It's a flying machine/device

Takes many forms

> Many implementations/different models

And is a controversial norm

> UAV use is controversial in war but it's becoming common as technology advances

An encounter with it
Will leave one tearful

> A UAV attack is fairly targeted and will leave bystanders who aren't killed tearful

And as an omen
It makes many fearful

> It has become a symbol of American aggression in the middle east (I'm not positive that this is true, but expect that it is)

Though as journeyers swear
It's useful where
One wants to prevent
Spoiled fare

> This is kind of a stretch but using drones as an alternative to bombing the heck out of a place helps prevent massive civilian casualties and destruction of infrastructure. Alternately, you could say using drones as an alternative to sending in ground troops spares the lives of your soldiers.

Another similar possibility

> Missiles